# iOS: UIViewController is Not Being Pushed Problem

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload, pushviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm working on a new app where there is a "main" UIViewController with some UIButtons and once the user clicks on the buttons, the application is navigating to another UIViewController.

For some reason, the UIViewControllers are not opened, when you click on the button nothing happens. Several points that anyone who tries to help should be aware of

- I'm using code and interface that are very similar to another app that I had created and is working fine (I triple checked the code, and it's the same in the area that makes the UIViewControllers navigation)
- I triple checked the Interface Builder items and their connection to the IBOutlet us fine (view is connected to view, File's Owner is set correctly, etc...)
- I inserted NSLogs to the UIViewController that is not being pushed and I can see that initWithNibName is being called, but viewDidLoad is not being called.
- I'm using basic-simple code to create and push the UIViewController: alloc+initWithNibName and then presentModalViewController or pushViewController (none of them work) and as I said, in another app with the same mechanism it works fine.

I don't know where to look! Maybe I unchecked by mistake some "Enable" button in Interface Builder or something like that.

Did anyone encounter something like that or may have some new thought regarding to where I should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, strange. Things i can come up with now are: dit you call [super ] in your viewDidLoad?
Is it stacked behind another view? Run instruments to see if all the things on the pushed view are allocated, so you know if the whole view is loaded. And you use a navigation controller? than you use pushViewController. When you are not and want a model you use presentmodalviewcontroller.